# I switched from ADT to Android Studio: You uploaded an APK that is signed with a different certificate to your previous APKs

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, google-play, adt

Please read before you post as a duplicate! I am using the same certificate, the only one I have used for years on multiple apps. I have run keytool on the jks I am using and the SHA1 key is the same as Google Play says was used to sign the last accepted apk. I have also run jarsigner on both the new apk and the last accepted one, and they show the exact same certificate information, dates, etc. The only change is I switched from ADT to Android Studio, and I can still upload using ADT using the same cert. And, for the record, the SHA that Google Play says I signed the new apk with is not my debug SHA either. Any ideas? I really don't want to go back to ADT!

Comment: Update: I confirmed my cert is correct by signing the apk via the command line tools. Google Play accepts the resulting apk. Android Studio is doing something wrong here it seems.

Answer (score 0):

This thing is when you first installed your app (from ADT) into your emulator or android device, it was made from ADT, but now you are trying to install the same app, from Android Studio, that is why you are getting this error : **You uploaded an APK that is signed with a different certificate to your previous APKs**

What you have to do is, first uninstall the previous version of your app from your device (which was installed when using ADT)... And then install the latest APK, by using Android Studio.

You dont have to go back to ADT. Keep using Android Studio, as it is the official IDE for Android Developement.

**Edit:** For Google Play i am not sure what can be the solution, as i dont know if u can delete an old signed APK and add a new one signed by the same certificate... Switching from ADT to Studio usually gives these kind of problems.

Comment: Faizy_Flash, thanks for your detailed answer. I appreciate it. But my issue is with submitting the app to Google Play, and there are no devices involved in that of course. I now believe there must be a bug in Android Studio given my comment I added above?

Comment: oh, sorry i didn't pay attention to the part where you said that u were trying to submit the app on the Google play, But i still think this bug arises when first u create your APK from different IDE, and then when you try to make APK of the same project from Android Studio, this bug arises. So like a real device or emulator, even the Google Play is giving u this response, but i am not sure about what can be done, if this occurs for Google Play

Comment: I have also encountered this problem (But only while installing on my android device).. For which deleting the old APK and installing the new one (created from Android Studio) always did the trick for me.